# React not rendering custom elements (babel + webpack)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I created an app using `create-react-app` and started to use webpack and babel.
What I get from this code is that I cannot render my components (example, `<App />`).
I can only render elements like h1 or h2, even if I import App in index.js (and don't use it), I cannot see anything.

I run with `npm run dev-server`.

`webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['@babel/react']
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
    }
};
```

`index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';

import './style.css';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="mainContainer">
                <h1>Test h1</h1>
                <h2>Test h2</h2>
                <p>Test p</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

`package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "smartpharma-front",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "react": "^16.12.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
        "react-scripts": "^3.3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack --mode=development",
        "build": "webpack --mode=production",
        "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "13.3.0",
        "npm": "6.13.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.7",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "css-loader": "^3.4.0",
        "style-loader": "^1.1.1",
        "webpack": "^4.41.4",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
    },
    "description": "SmartPharma Frontend",
    "main": "webpack.config.js",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/vfeder6/smartpharma-front.git"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/vfeder6/smartpharma-front/issues"
    },
    "homepage": "https://github.com/vfeder6/smartpharma-front#readme"
}
```

Comment: What are normal elements?

Comment: standard DOM elements, like h1, h2, p, etc...

Comment: What exactly do you want, you put <App> component and you get to see h1,h2, p which is received from <App> component render

Comment: Hey can you please share package.json and command you are using to run server

Comment: I cannot see what should be rendered in <App /> component. What I get is a blank page. If I delete <App />, delete the import and insert <h1>Hello, world</h1> I can see Hello, world but of course it is not the goal.

Comment: @NikhilPathania you can find my package.json in the question, the command is npm run dev-server